# Does a solution in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ imply solution in $\mathbb{Q}$ for every system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us assume that the system of linear U equations with integers has a solution in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Is that true that U also has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}$?

I think that it is true because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is an subfield of $\mathbb{Q}$. Can somebody make it clear for me why is that exacty?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The opposite of what you wrote is true.  $\mathbb Q$ is a subfield of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$.  $\sqrt2\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ but $\sqrt2\not\in\mathbb Q$

Comment: Thank you Sir! Are you sure? I thought that $Q$ is bigger and contains every element of $Q\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains **both** $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$. How could $\mathbb{Q}$ be bigger?

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you for your answer Sir :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a system of linear equations with integer (equiv. rational) coefficients,
$$\begin{align*}
a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + \cdots + a_{1n}x_n &= b_1\\
&\vdots\\
a_{m1}x_1 + a_{m2}x_2 + \cdots + a_{mn}x_n &= b_m
\end{align*}$$
with each $a_{ij},b_k\in\mathbb{Z}$ (or in $\mathbb{Q}$), and this system has a solution $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, then it also has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}$, but not for the (incorrect, as noted by J.W. Tanner) reason you state. Every element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ can be written uniquely as $r+s\sqrt{2}$ with $r,s\in\mathbb{Q}$. So if $x_i=r_i+s_i\sqrt{2}$ is a solution, then the $j$ equation says
$$\begin{align*}
b_j &= a_{j1}(r_1+s_1\sqrt{2}) + a_{j2}(r_2+s_2\sqrt{2}) + \cdots + a_{jn}(r_n+s_n\sqrt{2})\\
&= (a_{j1}r_1+\cdots+a_{jn}r_n) + (a_{j_1}s_1+\cdots+a_{jn}s_n)\sqrt{2},
\end{align*}$$
hence
$$a_{j1}r_1+\cdots+a_{jn}r_n = b_j \text{ and }a_{j1}s_1+\cdots+a_{jn}s_n=0.$$
In particular, $x_j=r_j$ is a rational solution.

Comment: I am fairly new to the forum and pretty much the whole concept of fields / subfields. I know that my question doesn't provide that much of value to others. That is I'm especially thankful for your time and effort!

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of what you wrote is true.

$\mathbb Q$ is a subfield of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$.

$\sqrt2\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ but $\sqrt2\not\in\mathbb Q$, i.e., $\sqrt2$ is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you perform Gaussian elimination over $\mathbb{Q}$ on the augmented matrix corresponding to the original system.  Then each step is also valid over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and thus results in an equivalent system whether the field you are working over is $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

At the end, once you have reached a matrix in row echelon form, or in reduced row echelon form (and either condition is independent of the exact scalar field), then over either field, a solution exists if and only if no row in the echelon form matrix corresponds to an equation $0 x_1 + \cdots + 0 x_n = b$ with $b \ne 0$.  This condition, too, is independent of the exact scalar field.

Comment: Of course the important point is that since the matrix has coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, you never need to multiply a row by a scalar in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, or add a $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$-multiple-that-is-not-a-$\mathbb{Q}$-mulitple of a row to another row; you need that observation to go from “the system over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$” to “the system over $\mathbb{Q}$”.